# Is always true for the formula of marginal density function from joint distribution?

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, marginal-distribution, marginal-probability

This is the formula to help you get the marginal pdf from a joint distribution:

$$f(x)= \int_{}^{} f(x,y) \, dy\\$$
$$f(y)= \int_{}^{} f(x,y) \, dx\\$$

where the first integral is over all points in the range of (X,Y) for which X=x and the second inegral is over all points in the range of (X,Y) for which Y=y.

I have no problem to get the marginal in sample case, like f(x,y)=1/x, for 0<x<10, 0<y<5.

However, I don't think that those formula will work on the case below:
$$f(x,y)= \frac{8}{3}xy $$
$$for\;0\le x\le1,x\le y\le 2x$$

Y is dependent on X for Y's region.

Can anyone give me a key word or hint? And then I can search more for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still find the marginal PDF - it's just going to be a piecewise function. Firstly - finding ${f(x) = \int_{x}^{2x}f(x,y)dy}$ is nice and straight forward. For ${f(y)}$ - we need to rewrite the bounds. If you do so, you'll notice it splits in two:
$$
0\leq y\leq 1,\frac{y}{2}\leq x\leq y
$$
$$
1 < y \leq 2,\frac{y}{2}\leq x < 1
$$
So
$$
f(y) = \left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
\int_{\frac{y}{2}}^{y}f(x,y)dx&\text{ if ${0\leq y\leq 1}$}\\
\int_{\frac{y}{2}}^{1}f(x,y)dx&\text{ if ${1 < y \leq 2}$}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Notice now that if you integrate ${\int_{0}^{2}f(y)dy}$, we should get $1$ - and you see that
$$
\int_{0}^{2}f(y)dy = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{\frac{y}{2}}^{y}f(x,y)dxdy + \int_{1}^{2}\int_{\frac{y}{2}}^{1}f(x,y)dxdy = 1
$$

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I can write the bounds with a graph. Did you use a graph to get those bounds? If not, could you share your skills? I am very bad at this. I only can do when x=1, then, 1<=y<=2. So, y's upper bound is 2. And because minimum of x is 0, so when x=0, then y should be 0. And y's lower bound is 0. I knew those are wrong. But I don't know where problem is.